# Undefined userId in empty Array php

Tags: php

I am using following code

```
           # fetch these users.
            $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM weenkDetails WHERE userId = :userId AND weenkedId IN (' . implode(',', $userIds) . ')'); 
            $statement->bindParam(':userId'    , $userId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->execute();

            while ($newRow = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $weenks[] = $newRow;
            }
            # assign weenks to users.
            # assign users to posts.
            foreach ($users as $index => $user)
            {
                $users[$index]['weenk'] = "null";
                foreach ($weenks as $weenk)
                {
                    if ($user['id'] == $weenk['weenkedId'])
                    {
                        $users[$index]['weenk'] = $weenk;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM weenkDetails WHERE weenkedId = :userId AND type = 2 AND userId IN (' . implode(',', $userIds) . ')');
            $statement->bindParam(':userId'    , $userId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->execute();
            $newWeenks[] = array();
            while ($newRow = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $newWeenks[] = $newRow;
            }

            # assign weenks to users.
            # assign users to posts.
            foreach ($users as $index => $user)
            {
                foreach ($newWeenks as $weenk)
                {
                    if ($user['id'] == $weenk['userId'])
                    {
                        $users[$index]['weenk'] = $weenk;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Initially as a test case my $weenks[] and $newWeenks[] are empty arrays.

```
foreach ($users as $index => $user)
                {
                    $users[$index]['weenk'] = "null";
                    foreach ($weenks as $weenk)
                    {
                        if ($user['id'] == $weenk['weenkedId'])
                        {
                            $users[$index]['weenk'] = $weenk;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Here everything works fine, nothing in array nothing happens

but later here

```
foreach ($users as $index => $user)
                {
                    foreach ($newWeenks as $weenk)
                    {
                        if ($user['id'] == $weenk['userId'])
                        {
                            $users[$index]['weenk'] = $weenk;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

it gives me error undefined index userId for $weenk

I have checked newWeenks is EMPTY returning it gives [] then how come it enters the loop? and why am  i getting this error here and not in above loop?

My table contains, `id  userId  weeenkedId  type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting bad your init array, you have: `$newWeenks[] = array();`

You must have: `$newWeenks = array();`